# Make default user to be root

Tags: users

First thing to do when I turn on my PC is using command `sudo -s` so instead of name@pc, I use user root@pc.

How do I make it to be default user and what are risks of my approach?

Comment: Please install another operating system than a debian based one if you want to use a root user as default. Debian based systems are set up with `sudo` for improved security reasons and safety. It comes with Ubuntu and is the way Ubuntu is supposed to be used. And I agree: if you already do not know how to do this you are not ready for it ;-)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why do you need a root session permanently open?

Comment: Please read [Why is it bad to login as root?](/q/16178/175814)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you do not know how to unlock root, you are not yet ready for its unleashed powers!**

In Ubuntu, the `root` account is disabled by default so that no login is possible. You can only run commands as root using `sudo`.

This is because as `root`, every little mistake in a command you type or every malicious executable you run can mess up your entire system.

There's the principle to always run everything with the least privileges needed to complete the task to prevent escalation.

Stop using the interactive `root` shell and place `sudo` in front of every command that really needs elevated privilege. It's better for you.

Comment: Good advice, however the best lessons come from experience.

Comment: @Kunok Logging in as root is like playing with an armed gun. Both comes with a high risk to shoot yourself into the foot sooner or later unless you really know what you do. I will warn everyone who asks me to stay away from both.

Comment: @Kunok See [Principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) on Wikipedia